# HTML table with 100% of height, and the rows equally divided in height. How to make it possible?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please go through [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmand/VDXg2/) to see what I have tried so far.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <table style="background-color: red; width:100%; height:100%;">
            <tr style="background-color: red; width:100%; min-height:30%;">
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: blue; width:100%; min-height:30%;">
                <td>Nirman</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: blue; width:100%; min-height:30%;">
                <td>Nirman</td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to display this table occupying full height of the div, and rows of this table should be equal in height to occupy space of full table.
That means, table's height should be 100% of div's height.
and each row's height should be 30% of div's height.

Any idea of how to achieve this? Also, I would like a solution that should work on most of the browsers, at least, starting from IE 8.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: can you use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: yes, of course, but will that be an accurate one?

Comment: isn't it possible through CSS itself?

Comment: I am not really sure that it is possible with pure css unless `.inner`  have fixed height

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In styles of the `inner` div class, change `min-height:100%` to `height:100%` .
That's all you need!

(This is because `min-height` can not be inherited)

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQqUF/)

Comment: that's awesome, I have used min-height like anything in my project... and now removing from everywhere... this is working great.

Answer (score 3):

Through CSS , you have to set height of .inner . min-height value cannot be inherited :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yuEkA
 a short cut would be :

```
html, body , .outer, .inner {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can position the table absolute. For example, give it the class "full-height", and then add the following css:

```
table.full-height {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This will expand the table to the full height!

Comment: not working, it taking whole screen, I want to show it under the div only, as you can see in fiddle, that the table is inside DIV

Answer (score 1):

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}
table{
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}


<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#FF0000">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#00FF00">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#0000FF">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDXg2/8/)!

Answer (score -3):

jQuery solution for making 30% `tr` height

```
var t_h = $('.inner').height()

var tr_h = t_h/100*30

$('tr').height(tr_h)
$('table').height(t_h);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDXg2/6/)